# What does the idiom "venir de maleta" mean?

Tags: modismos, chile

While in Chile I heard the idiom *venir de maleta*.  I was told that it means something along the lines of "to be angry," but I'm not seeing any evidence of this online.  It's theoretically possible that I misheard, but I don't think so.

Thus, my questions: What does the phrase mean?  Does it have shades of meaning not covered by *enojarse*? And is it used outside Chile as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had never heard this expression. Upon research I could find that the expression does not only use "venir" but also "estar", "andar", etc.

Then, I found out that DRAE has a mention to it, in which it indicates that it is typical from Chile, no other countries:

> [maleta<sup>3</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?w=maleta&o=h)
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que practica con torpeza o desacierto la profesión que ejerce.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Mal torero.
> 3. m. y f. Guat. Persona perversa.
>
> a la maleta
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Chile. a traición. Le pegó a la maleta.
>
> **andar alguien de maletas**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **Chile. Estar de mal humor.**

As you see, "maleta" has this connotation of "dumb", so a translation would be like "acting dumb", which in some cases can be seen as "acting bad 
tempered".

I don't think it is a synonym of *enojarse*, since this means to get angry, probably as a result of something. However, in this case is most likely to refer to a continuous feeling: you wake up and feel bad tempered.

Comment: Thanks!  Good point; I should have compared it to *estar enojado*, not *enojarse*, but this is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I want compliment the accepted response indicating something that is quite obvious for speakers of Spanish and therefore not specified:

The idiom "andar de maleta" comes from "andar de mal humor" (or "de mala cara"). This is a rhetorical game called **paronomasia** in which a signifier is replaced with another very similar, in this case "**mal** humor" for "**mal**eta". It's probably what the English call "pun", I'm not sure.

Paronomasia is really very very very common among Chileans. I do not know if this also happens in other countries, but there are lots of examples that are part of our local dictionary. Examples:

- Andar de maleta = andar con mal humor
- ¡Holanda! = ¡hola!
- ¿Y Bosnia? = ¿y vos? (es irónico: *¿acaso tú no?*)
- ¿Cómo andamio? = ¿cómo andamos? (*¿cómo te va?*)
- ¡Albornoz! = ¡ah, vos no! (*¿y acaso tú no?*)
- No seas Contreras = no estés siempre en mi contra (Contreras is a surname)
- ¿Cómo le baila? = cómo te va
- ¿Qué container? = ¿qué cuentas?
- Todo viento = todo bien

Comment: ¡Interesantísima respuesta! Ninguna de los ejemplos que mencionas se usan en España, a parte tal vez de *¿Qué me estás container?* (¿qué me estás contando?).