# ¿Por qué en Chile se dice "hacerlo a la paraguaya" para "hacerlo de pie"?

Tags: expresiones, chile

Buscando información para [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27170/12637) encuentro en el *Diccionario de americanismos*:

> **[paraguaya](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=paraguaya)**.
>
> a. ǁ  **a la ~**. loc. adv. Ch. Realizando el coito de pie. pop + cult →
>   espon ^ fest.

Así que no puedo evitar preguntar, ¿por qué en Chile se dice "a la paraguaya" para el acto de realizar el coito de pie?

Comment: A los chilenos nos gusta la paronomasia, pongo otros ejemplos en esta respuesta acerca de la expresión [andar de maleta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16488/6915). También de índole sexual tenemos la expresión "por Detroit".

Comment: @Rodrigo enlacé la pregunta en Reddit y las respuestas allí son todas del estilo, he aprendido un montón de chilenismos paronomásicos hoy. Me ha encantado, ¡comunicarse en Chile tiene que ser lo más divertido del mundo! :-D

Comment: @Charlie ¡No sabes cuánto!

Answer (score 8):

This is not a documented answer, but as a Chilean and knowing that we Chilean like a lot to play with words, I would say it is just a deformation of the word **parado**, and an assimilation to the word **Paraguay**, just like when we rhetorically ask after stating something: ¿onofre?, we deform the original question ¿o no? and assimilate it to the name Onofre...

Answer (score 4):

Si hay algo complicado de entender es como los chilenos — y me incluyo — somos capaces de modificar y/o deformar expresiones.

Cuando a uno le dicen *a la paraguaya*, lo primero que se hace es cuestionar qué es.
Muchos utilizan la expresión sin conocer su significado; esto deja una interrogante.
Sin embargo, quienes la conocen te dirán la definición — o alguna explicación parecida — de lo que en realidad es.

Puede que la coincidencia sea por el inicio de cada palabra ***para***guaya y ***para***do, que es lo que ya se mencionó en otra respuesta, pero los orígenes pueden llegar a ser aún más arcanos; además, si hay algo que es pan de cada día de nosotros, es llegar y usar expresión porque se nos dio la gana y, en muchos casos, ni siquiera porque exista alguna correlación.